# best way for using famous in mobile meteor apps?

Tags: node.js, meteor, famo.us

I would like to create an example app (native iOS/android) with meteor and famous but I´m a little bit confused about the syntax of famous in some meteor projects. It looks like there are some projects that integrate famous packages into meteor like **mjn:famous** but other projects use **gadicohen:famous-views** package.

I tried the famous university tutorials and everything was fine but in meteor I have to use the [famous-views](http://famous-views.meteor.com/start) syntax like:

```
  {{#famousContext id="mainCtx"}}
    {{#Surface}}
      I am a full size Surface
    {{/Surface}}
  {{/famousContext}}
```

the famous-meteor thing is not very well documentated and I can't find good tutorials how to combine them because there are so many packages. So whats the best or right way to integrate famous into meteor for native mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new package that I have created for this purpose. The package name is 'sgi:famous-angular'. This package automatically includes two other packages: one which loads angular for you and the other that loads famous for you. My package will load the current version of famous-angular. I have a sample app up on github that demonstrates how to use this package:

https://github.com/pavlovich/meteor-angular-famous-demo

The only thing you need keep in mind is that you will have to include the following CSS in your main application CSS file in order to ensure that automatic layout in the vertical dimension works correctly:

```
fa-app {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

If you have any further questions or comments, please let me know and I will see what I can do to help you out.

Comment: I just have read a little bit about the integration. can I use the angular/famous/ integration in meteor to build native iOS/Android app out of the box with `meteor run ios/android`?

Comment: Yes you can! I just created a package to make it easy to do just that very thing! The package is 'sgi:famous-angular'. I've updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Note that there is a current bug if you are using 'batarang', the Google Chrome Angular debugging plug-in, in that manually bootstrapped angular apps will fail to initialize as batarang seems to pre-bootstrap the document. Thus, when your app attempts to bootstrap itself manually, it fails with an 'already bootstrapped' error message in the console. This is apparently not an issue if you are using ng-app to bootstrap your app. Apparently, the plugin author is working on a solution. For now, just disable batarang.